# Wordpress Custom Field - shorter code

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to write shorter code then?
I'm starting with php/wordpress...

```
<?php while( have_rows('members') ):
    the_row(); 
    // vars
    $image = get_sub_field('member_picture');
    $member = get_sub_field('member');
    $link = get_sub_field('member_link');
    $link2 =ltrim($link, "http://");
    $memberabout = get_sub_field('member_about')
    ?>
    <div class="members">
        <div class="member"><?php echo $member; ?></div>
        <div class="memberpicture"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" /></div>
        <div class="memberabout"><?php echo $memberabout; ?></div>
        <div class="memberlink"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link2; ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Why do You want to shorten Your code? I think it's the shortest as possible and looks good.

Comment: I thought mayby the link (memberlink)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to shorten the code, you might try it like this :

```
<?php while( have_rows('members') ): the_row(); 
     $image = get_sub_field('member_picture');
?>
    <div class="members">
        <div class="member"><?php echo get_sub_field('member'); ?></div>
        <div class="memberpicture"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" /></div>
        <div class="memberabout"><?php echo get_sub_field('member_about'); ?></div>
        <div class="memberlink"><a href="<?php echo get_sub_field('member_link'); ?>"><?php echo ltrim($link, "http://"); ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the need for the callouts on some of the fields like so:

```
<?php
while (have_rows('members')): the_row();
$image = get_sub_field('member_picture');
?>
<div class="members">
    <div class="member"><?php echo get_sub_field('member'); ?></div>
    <div class="memberpicture"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" /></div>
    <div class="memberabout"><?php echo get_sub_field('member_about'); ?></div>
    <div class="memberlink"><a href="<?php echo get_sub_field('member_link'); ?>"><?php echo ltrim(get_sub_field('member_link'), "http://"); ?></a></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The only one i can see being really required is the callout for the image due to it coming out as an array.